# Remove hook function from parent theme in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, themes

I've read several guides and posts here on stackoverflow, but I can't see why on my case it isn't working.

In my parent Porto theme there in the file:
`themes/porto/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php`

there is this piece of code:

```
if ( 'list' == $view_mode || ( isset( $porto_settings['product-desc'] ) && $porto_settings['product-desc'] ) ) {
    if ( ! has_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt' ) ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt', 9 );
    }
} elseif ( has_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt', 9 );
}
```

So in my child theme's `functions.php` I have tried:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_my_parent_theme_function');

function remove_my_parent_theme_function() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt', 9);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_my_parent_theme_function');

function remove_my_parent_theme_function() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt', 9);
}
```

I have also tried other stuff that I've lost track of them, but I don't get why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can override this `themes/porto/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php` file your child theme.

**1) Create `woocommerce` folder in the child theme.**

**2) Create `loop` folder inside woocommerce**

**3) Now copy `loop-start.php` from the parent theme and copy to the child theme `woocommerce > loop` folder.**

**4) Now comment out code that you want to remove by action.**

```
if ( 'list' == $view_mode || ( isset( $porto_settings['product-desc'] ) && $porto_settings['product-desc'] ) ) {
    if ( ! has_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt' ) ) {
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt', 9 );
    }
} elseif ( has_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'porto_woocommerce_single_excerpt', 9 );
}
```

Comment: I know but this is kind of shabby no? because in my child theme there would be way more code with potential to be replaced by an update than if I could just remove the hook function and replace that function.

Comment: No, it's not shabby. you have now more control of the action.